# Overwrite settings

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, settings

when my app is opened you have to fill in some line, like your name, weight and length and then it saves this by pressing an Floating Action Button(it saves it to an activity called Util). Later, I want to give the user the ability to edit these settings in a settingsFragment when he/she clicks a button. I have some code, but it won't work and I have no idea how to fix this, can someone help me out please?

Here is the code from my first screen:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       String length = inputLength.getText().toString();
                       String weight = inputWeight.getText().toString();
                       int Length = Integer.parseInt(length);
                       int Weight = Integer.parseInt(weight);
                       Util.get().setName(inputName.getText().toString());
                       Util.get().setLength(Length);
                       Util.get().setWeight(Weight);
                       Integer lengthValue = Integer.parseInt(length);
                       Integer weightValue = Integer.parseInt(weight);

                       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("be.ugent.MyApplication", MODE_PRIVATE);
                       prefs.edit().putString("name", inputName.getText().toString()).apply();
                       prefs.edit().putInt("weight", weightValue).apply();
                       prefs.edit().putInt("length", lengthValue).apply();

                       Intent main = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                       startActivity(main);
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                   }
               });
```

And this is my settingsFragment

```
Button save = (Button)settingsView.findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String length = inputLength.getText().toString();
            String weight = inputWeight.getText().toString();
            int Length = Integer.parseInt(length);
            int Weight = Integer.parseInt(weight);
            Util.get().setName(inputName.getText().toString());
            Util.get().setLength(Length);
            Util.get().setWeight(Weight);
            Integer lengthValue = Integer.parseInt(length);
            Integer weightValue = Integer.parseInt(weight);

            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("be.ugent.MyApplication", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit().putString("name", inputName.getText().toString()).commit();
            prefs.edit().putInt("weight", weightValue).commit();
            prefs.edit().putInt("length", lengthValue).commit();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Gegevens opgeslagen",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });

    inputName.setText(Util.get().getName());
```

Cheers!